# In PHP, how to implement interface in a method, not implement on a class?

Tags: php, interface

In PHP, how to implement interface in a method, not implement on a class?
such as java code:

```
interface TestInterface{
    void test(String param);
}
public class Test(){
    private static TestInterface testInterface;
    public static  void setTestInterface(TestInterface testInterface){
        this.testInterface=testInterface;
    }
    public static void action(){
        this.testInterface.test("param") ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test test =new Test();
        test.setTestInterface(new TestInterface(){
            @Override
            public void test(String p){
               System.out.print(p);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you are trying to create an anonymous class that implements the interface in Php and you want to pass the anonymous class to `.setTestInterface()`?

Comment: I don't want to create an anonymous class that implements the interface. I just want to use method to implement it